# Set model value in anchor tag style

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, styles, anchor

and i want change the color in dynamically ,I used the colors are assigned in one property from my model class

My model class property name is `color`

Now i want to call this property to my anchor tag style property

i tried this

```
<a  href="@Model.AnnualBudget" `**style="color: @model.Color"**` target="_blank">
                        AnnualBudget</a>
```

But my code is not worked , you have any idea for this ?Please help me

Thanks Ramesh ,

Comment: Is `@model.Color` is typo error, It should be `@Model.Color`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat `Model.Color` value as a string and assign it to the style attribute like this:

```
<a  href="@Model.AnnualBudget" style="@("color: "+Model.Color)" target="_blank">
                        AnnualBudget</a>
```